# Converting xls to xlsx and deleting the old file

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following macro to convert an xls file to xlsx.  The problem with it is the line that says `SaveAs`.  This creates a second file, one with the original xls extension and the second with the xlsx extension.  If I simply say Save, I get an error.  How can I either delete the xls file or have the macro do a Save instead of SaveAs?  The reason we need to convert the file is so that when we email the file it is smaller in size.

```
Dim s As String
s = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
s = Replace(s, "xls", "xlsx")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=s, _
      FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: There are two separate operations here - Creating a new file (in xlsx format) and deleting an old file.  There really isn't a way around this.  Sounds like you have the first task covered.  Here's some answer related to the second: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835/deleting-a-file-in-vba

Answer (score 1):

In terms of saving your current file, you have 2 choices:  overwrite your current file (with the same type), or generate a **new** file.  This is a limitation (feature?) of Excel, not VBA.

So, to acheive what you want, we will need to do some more work.  What we need for this is the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706(v=vs.60).aspx).  This basically allows you to interact with the files and directories on your computer through VBA.  The first thing we need to do is keep the original file name;  This will allow us to delete it by name.  From there, we will create the `FileSystemObject`, and use it to call the `DeleteFile` method.  So, your code should look like

```
Dim old_name As String, new_name As String
old_name = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
new_name = Replace(old_name, "xls", "xlsx")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=new_name, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

Dim FSO as FileSystemObject
Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
FSO.DeleteFile old_name
Set FSO = Nothing
```

Note that you will need to set a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` in order to create and use a FileSystemObject.