# How to copy a file to a folder if there is already a file with the same name?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write an Excel VBA macro that will loop through a list of folder paths, fetch all the files inside these folders and copy them to a single folder. Everything works fine until the macro reaches to a file that already exists in the destination folder, and then it returns the message: "run time error 70 - permission denied"

here's the code I'm currently using:

```
FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=topath
```

If possible, I would prefer to overwrite the duplicate files.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not try deleting the file first if it already exists? [see here for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835/deleting-a-file-in-vba)

Comment: I will resort to that option if all else fails.

Comment: Anything special about the file that it stops at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CopyFolder` method has an optional *OverWriteFiles* argument...

```
FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=topath, OverWriteFiles:=True
```

Comment: it gives me this message: "runtime error 448 - named argument not found"

Comment: Corrected argument name to OverWriteFiles. Try that.

Comment: The problem is not that the file exists then. Still researching.

Comment: really does sound like a permissions issue

Comment: yes, you were right, I changed folder permissions - now it works like a charm! Do you know if there's a vba code to change folder's permissions?