# SaveAs non-workbook file using vba

Tags: vba, macros, excel-2010, save-as

I have a series of .xml files that are used as data sources for our customers, viewed through an Excel "template", which populates tables etc. from the .xml.

Each month, we get new .xml files on the server and one of our users runs a macro which adds the .xml files in turn to the template, saving the template each time with a new name corresponding to the name of the .xml file it now shows.

I would like add a step to this macro, to move each .xml file to a new archive location. Ideally this would look the same as a cut/paste operation, removing the .xml file from the original location. I know how to delete a file using vba (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835/deleting-a-file-in-vba) question), but not how to SaveAS a file that is not a workbook... How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I'll try the suggestion in the possible duplicate and comment if it solves the problem, making it genuinely a duplicate - I agree it looks like it will be.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is a duplicate. Thanks for pointing this out and pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad the other question helped you.