# Deleting a specific file inside a zipped file

Tags: excel, zip, vba

Is there any way I can delete a file inside a zipped file using Excel VBA? I have the zipped file directory and like to delete a specific file inside it. Any suggestions?Thanks.

Comment: Why not unzip the zip file, delete the file you require and zip it all again? More info to zip: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win002.htm and to delete files: http://stackoverflow.com/q/67835/6671476

Comment: You might want to have a look at the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211/can-windows-built-in-zip-compression-be-scripted