# Macro to delete a file from location and then save in a different location?

Tags: excel, vba, save

i have created a macro to save a sheet to a specific location (see below):
    Sub Savefileas()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Unprotect Password:="Spiralbevel1"
ws.EnableSelection = xlNoSelection
ws.Protect Password:="Spiralbevel1", DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
Next ws

Dim ThisFile As String
Dim varResult As Variant
ThisFile = Range("B4").Value
varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
"Macro Enabled Workbook" & "(*.xlsm), *xlsm", Title:=ThisFile & ".xlsm", InitialFileName:="G:\New Manufacturing Engineering\Gear Shop\Spiral Bevel\Miscellaneous\Stock Removal Test File\Stock Removals with Errors\ " & ThisFile & ".xlsm")
With ActiveWorkbook
    On Error GoTo message
    .SaveAs varResult & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
    Exit Sub
message:
    MsgBox "There is an error"
End With
End Sub
```

This sheet needs to be reviewed and then saved to a different location using this macro:

```
Sub Savefileas()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Unprotect Password:="Spiralbevel1"
ws.EnableSelection = xlNoSelection
ws.Protect Password:="Spiralbevel1", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
Next ws

Dim ThisFile As String
Dim varResult As Variant
ThisFolder = Range("B2").Value
ThisFile = Range("B4").Value
varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
"Macro Enabled Workbook" & "(*.xlsm), *xlsm", Title:=ThisFolder & ThisFile & ".xlsm", InitialFileName:="G:\New Manufacturing Engineering\Gear Shop\Spiral Bevel\Miscellaneous\Stock Removal Test File\" & ThisFolder & "\ " & ThisFile & ".xlsm")
With ActiveWorkbook
    On Error GoTo message
    .SaveAs varResult & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
    Exit Sub
message:
    MsgBox "There is an error"
End With
End Sub
```

What i need to happen is the original file is deleted from the original folder is was saved to

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835/deleting-a-file-in-vba

Comment: `Kill` and then full path and name of the file.

Comment: This is fine but the file name will change on a different project, can i use the Kill command and link it to a cell with the file name in: i have tried Kill (Range("H2")) but it didnt work

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264639.aspx - this may help