# Extract Zipped file from Outlook mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to extract an zip file from my Outlook mail.

Below is my script but its throwing an error object variable or with block variable not set.

On

```
oApp.NameSpace((FileNameFolder)).CopyHere oApp.NameSpace((Atchmt.FileName)).Items
```

How I fix it.

```
Sub Unzip()
Dim ns As NameSpace
Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim Atchmt As Attachment
Dim FileName As String
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim FileNameFolder As String
Dim FSO As Object               'variables for unzipping
Dim oApp As Object

Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("TEST")

For Each msg In SubFolder.Items
   If msg.UnRead = True Then
        If LCase(msg.Subject) Like "*motor*" Then
            For Each Atchmt In msg.Attachments
                If (Right(Atchmt.FileName, 3) = "zip") Then
                MsgBox "1"
                        FileNameFolder = "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\test\"
                        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                        oApp.NameSpace((FileNameFolder)).CopyHere oApp.NameSpace((Atchmt.FileName)).Items

                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: oApp.NameSpace((FileNameFolder)).CopyHere oApp.NameSpace((Atchmt.FileName)).Items

Comment: Save the zip first then extract it

Comment: Yes its working in the way you said but i want only the csv file

Comment: Once you extract the file, Kill the zip file. Let me know if you need example on how to kill the zip.

Comment: Yes i do need... please help

Comment: `Dim FileNameFolder As Variant`  - does not like a string

Comment: Can i have a example code to kill the Zip file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try saving the zip file first then extract it, if you want to *[delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835/deleting-a-file-in-vba)* the zip file then try **`Kill (zippath & zipname )`**

```
    Dim TempFile As String

    For Each msg In SubFolder.Items
       If msg.UnRead = True Then
            If LCase(msg.Subject) Like "*motor*" Then
                For Each Atchmt In msg.Attachments
                    If (Right(Atchmt.FileName, 3) = "zip") Then
'                    MsgBox "1"
                        FileNameFolder = "C:\Temp\Folders\"

                        Debug.Print FileNameFolder ' Immediate Window
                        Debug.Print Atchmt.FileName ' Immediate Window

                        TempFile = FileNameFolder & Atchmt.FileName

                        Atchmt.SaveAsFile TempFile

                        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                        oApp.NameSpace((FileNameFolder)).CopyHere oApp.NameSpace((Atchmt.FileName)).Items

                        Kill (TempFile)

                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: This Worked like a charm! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Declare msg as a generic Object - you can have objects other than `MailItem` in the Inbox, such as `ReportItem` or `MeetingItem`.

Comment: What is the new error? What is the exact line of your code that raises that exception?

Comment: oApp.NameSpace((FileNameFolder)).CopyHere oApp.NameSpace((Atchmt.FileName)).Items   - With block variable not set  - this is the error

Comment: You never check if oApp.NameSpace (first or second) actually returns a valid object.