# Extracting zip content without administrator privileges

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to extract 7z content using VBA without administrator privileges?

Using the function [`UnzipAFile` described here](https://exceloffthegrid.com/vba-cod-to-zip-unzip/) I get an error at line:

```
ShellApp.Namespace(unzipToPath).CopyHere ShellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).items
```

I think it is related to the create object command:

```
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
```

I do not and cannot have administrator privileges.
(Maybe its due to other reason?!?)
Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42480900/4539709

Comment: Has it worked for you?

Comment: Using the `Shell.Application` via the `CreateObject` command didn't work for me but I managed to complete the task using the `sendkeys` combination.
I guess its because of no administrator privileges.
Thank you anyway.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0):

*See Ron de Bruin Example code-*

[Unzip file(s) with the default Windows zip program](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win002.htm)

```
Sub Unzip1()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim Fname As Variant
    Dim FileNameFolder As Variant
    Dim DefPath As String
    Dim strDate As String

    Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Zip Files (*.zip), *.zip", _
                                        MultiSelect:=False)
    If Fname = False Then
        'Do nothing
    Else
        'Root folder for the new folder.
        'You can also use DefPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test\"
        DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
            DefPath = DefPath & "\"
        End If

        'Create the folder name
        strDate = Format(Now, " dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss")
        FileNameFolder = DefPath & "MyUnzipFolder " & strDate & "\"

        'Make the normal folder in DefPath
        MkDir FileNameFolder

        'Extract the files into the newly created folder
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

        oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(Fname).items

        'If you want to extract only one file you can use this:
        'oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere _
         'oApp.Namespace(Fname).items.Item("test.txt")

        MsgBox "You find the files here: " & FileNameFolder

        On Error Resume Next
        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        FSO.deletefolder Environ("Temp") & "\Temporary Directory*", True
    End If

End Sub
```