# Replace the old file with new file

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

The code moves files from one folder to another. However, it stops if a file is already in the destination folder.

If a file with same name comes it should replace it with the new one.

```vb
Sub MoveFilesAccordingFileType()
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim Fl As Scripting.File
    Dim sourceFldr As Scripting.Folder
    Dim DestinationFldr As Scripting.Folder
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set sourceFldr = fso.GetFolder("E:\Deploy_The_Process\Add Limits")
    Set DestinationFldr = fso.GetFolder("E:\Deploy_The_Process\Archive\Word")
    For Each Fl In sourceFldr.Files
        If (fso.GetExtensionName(Fl.Path) = "docx") Then
            fso.MoveFile Fl.Path, DestinationFldr.Path & "/"
        End If
    Next Fl
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting a file in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835/deleting-a-file-in-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want your loop to have a conditional kill line like so:

```
    For Each Fl In sourceFldr.Files
        If (fso.GetExtensionName(Fl.Path) = "docx") Then
            If Dir(DestinationFldr.Path & "/" & Fl.Name) <> "" Then Kill DestinationFldr.Path & "/" & Fl.Name
            fso.MoveFile Fl.Path, DestinationFldr.Path & "/"
        End If
    Next Fl
```